# MVC in my java game. How do I connect the objects to the view

Tags: java, model-view-controller

Hayloo :)

I am trying to create a small rpg-game which implements the MVC design. I have created the following classes

1. Account <- has info about how many "Helpers" the user has. Also holds a list of all the characters unlocked
2. Weapons, Armors, etc etc
3. Character <- has an inventory and can do damage, level up and so on.
4. Helpers <- AI's to help the Character in combat
5. Monster <- monster the character will fight agains
6. Market <- a market place where the character can buy and sell stuff
7. Village <- this is the "home". you have options like: go to market, go to sleep and so on

Those classes would be my models right?

Right now I have some problems with the controller and the view. I actually don't know where to go next. How should I implement the controller and the view so they can use the model. The model is encapsulated so it shouldn't be a problem to receive data or set data.

Comment: The question is a bit unclear, there is so much to explain. You should rephrasing it so one can answer a concrete question.

Comment: My question is.. where the hell can i get a good book on mvc :D

Comment: read the section on mvc in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns, then read http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/uiArchs.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quintessential MVC paper is http://st-www.cs.illinois.edu/users/smarch/st-docs/mvc.html

I don't recommend you implement your MVC as described in this paper, there are more modern MVC design patterns.  Here are some more good articles:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/mvc-136693.html - based in Java, but great for anyone starting out with MVC.

http://www.javadude.com/articles/vaddmvc1/mvc1.htm - also based in Java and the discontinued VisualAge.  Has a walk through of creating an MVC application and all the example code.

Answer (score 0):

> My question is.. where the hell can i get a good book on mvc.

MVC is just a Pattern, this means an idea how to solve a common problem in a special way - but his requires that you andertand the problem. But to be honest, your question does not sounds like your problem is the one solved by MVC.

The probelm solved by MVC is a way to STRUCTURE the code and objects in a command oriented gui. It does not explain how to write games or any other kind of programmes. (Don´t anderstand me wrong, MVC is very usefull. But it discuss is only a small part, that makes programms more maintainable and readable, but really it does not solve any other problem then this two.)

So I would recommend that you write your game first without paying additional attention to MVC than you already have. So the first step is getting the program running. Then think about, what would you do in a different way when you need to write the programm again. This is the point where you should study the MVC pattern.

If you anderstand this, then you will also understand that there is noting more about the general MVC-Pattern then written in Wikipedia. Of course there will be a lot of frameworks that are build on MVC and there are a lot of books for this frameworks. But this books are more about the framework details in action than the MVC pattern.

Sorry

Comment: I disagree with this answer. There are LOTS of problems that one encounters as they are implementing MVC.  Some are due to the frame work, some are inherent in the design pattern.  So, although the basic design pattern is simple, there's lots to learn!  Not to mention there are many variations on how to implement MVC.  One variation gives the view no direct reference to the model.  A good book would be great, but I don't know of a good book on MVC, I've been looking.

Comment: @Jason: "There are LOTS of problems that one encounters as they are implementing MVC."  please be so fair and mention LOTS of probles SOLVED by MVC other then the ones I mentiond. BTW and MVC is Architecural and not a Design Pattern.